# Activate animations at specific scroll positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm creating a CV page, where I included animations - some of them work with additional library: Animate css. It works, but animations start when page is fully loaded - and I want them to happen when scrolled to position where div starts (It's in the middle of page)

I've tried to do that with element `.scrollTop`, but then I could include value only in px - and i need responsive page ( I use `calc()` )
There was also possibility that i did something wrong - but i haven't noticed

Just like I said - I want to start animations when div would become in range of sight.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possbile, if you combine JQuery with JavaScript DOM or with just JavaScript DOM.

My function might not be the best way, but it works and is fairly simple.

My example starts an Animation when the grey divs Top offset relative to the viewport is lower than 100.

(If you would like to use this make 2 css classes (1 with an animation, 1 without) and set the ID Strings to your HTML Ids)

```css
.Initial{
background-color: #ccc;
color: black;
position: fixed;
}
.AfterScroll{
background-color: #fff;
color: green;
position: fixed;
animation-name: Anim;
animation-duration: 1.4s;
}
@keyframes Anim{
25% {color: red;}
50% {color: blue;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#AnimationElementID" ).addClass("AfterScroll");
var set = false; // will be false on page load

$( window ).scroll(function() { //On Scroll Event Handler, Could also be window.onscroll (DOM)
   // JS HTML DOM get element position relative to viewport
  var rect = document.getElementById("AnimationElementTriggerDivID").getBoundingClientRect();
  // This is the offset at where your animation would start, 100 = div is 100px from viewport top
  if( rect.top <100 && set==false){ 
  $( "#AnimationElementID" ).toggleClass("Initial");
  $( "#AnimationElementID" ).toggleClass("AfterScroll");
  set=true; // so we only toggle the class once 
  }
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="Initial" id="AnimationElementID">
Hi im a text and I will change color if you scroll
</p>
<div id="AnimationElementTriggerDivID" style="background-color: #ccc; position: relative; top:200px; width:20px; height:2000px"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Maybe someone else can provide a better JQuery only option, or a cleaner function, but until then, feel free to use this.

PS: if possible, please provide Code snippets in order for people to be able to help you better and faster.